# Small text image clearification using image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

This is my input image:

[image]

I want to clear it in order to read the small text. The problem is that the image has noise in the bottom left part. How can I reduce the noise of the image?

Comment: Are these the original images or bad quality JPEGs that you used for posting ? If you don't have better quality sources, drop the idea.

Comment: The main reason is that the quality of the image is bad (not too much bad .. that the big text is readable but the small are not). but I need a solution with the image not another way. I prefer to find the way to fix it using image processing!!!!

Comment: Drop the idea, the quality on those left digits is awful.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Before and after denoting with OpenCV]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
    dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img, None, 10, 10, 7, 21)

    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img)
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst)
    plt.show()
```

Be sure to checkout more documentation [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_non_local_means/py_non_local_means.html)

Comment: not the big text actually (that is readable). It must  be the small text like (auto 10 min) or bottom left corner red small texts

Comment: It'll quickly process the image as a whole any noise